# C++11: Cannot capture `this` when trying to capture member of class in lambda function

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I'm writing a simple test to see how C++11 Lambdas can be used for the purpose of maximizing code reuse. I have a function, `fill_vector()` and in one case I'd like it to simply fill a vector with random numbers, but in another case I'd like it to also provide me with the maximum of those numbers.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

template <class Function>
void fill_vector(std::vector<int> &v, Function side)
{
    for(auto i=v.begin(); i!=v.end(); ++i)
    {
            *i = rand() % 100;
    }
    side.lambda(v);
}

class null_test
{
public:
    constexpr static auto lambda = [] (std::vector<int> x) { };
};

class test
{
public:
    test() : max(0) { } 

    int max;
    static auto lambda = [=] (std::vector<int> x) { max = 
        std::max_element(x.begin(),x.end()); };
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v(20);
    null_test n;
    fill_vector(v,n);

    std::copy(v.begin(),v.end(),std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout," "));

    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::vector<int> v2(20);
    test t;
    fill_vector(v2,t);
    std::copy(v.begin(),v.end(),std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout," "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << t.max << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Which results in the error: ‘this’ was not captured for this lambda function, pointing at my lambda defined in `test`. I've tried all sorts of capture statements and can't seem to get anything to work. What am I missing?

Also, is it possible to use a lambda inside the loop of `fill_vector` that could, say, extract every nth element filled? My goal here is to be able to reuse a function like `fill_vector` as much as possible for other functions that might need slight variations of it in a bigger project.

Comment: You couldn't set `max` from a static member function either; this is a similar issue.

Comment: @dyp So your suggestion would be to get rid of `static` and `auto` and replace with the appropriate version of `std::function`?

Comment: No, I don't think a lambda is even appropriate here. Also, I have no idea what the intent of the `fill_vector` algorithm is, since it also calls some function after doing the actual filling.

Comment: It *seems* as if you'd like to do something like this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02536733c0751459

Comment: @dyp exactly what I thought, and those functors (NOT their call-operators) can now be replaced nicely by lambdas, i.e. `max` can live in main and bound by ref

Comment: @dyp I'm trying to come up with a simple example of extending some existing useful function (in this case `fill_vector`) to handle other use cases for the purpose of code reuse. However, these other use cases might want slight variations on what `fill_vector` initially offers. Does that make sense?

Whether it uses lambdas or not isn't a huge deal, but I'd like to learn about them so here we are.

Comment: @leemes Oops, of course. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d849e5b2dbb927d

Comment: @dyp That's pretty much what I was looking for. I'll accept if you'd like to answer. I'd also appreciate alternatives to lambdas if you think there's a better solution to my  problem.

Comment: @Adam27X Then, why not `template <class C, class F> void fill_range(C &c, F f) { for(auto&& e : c) e = f(); }` as an example?

Comment: @dyp Because then I need different versions of `f()` that all have lots of overlapping code (though perhaps not in this simple example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your class `test`:

```
class test
{
public:
    int max;
    static auto lambda = [=] (std::vector<int> x) {
        max = std::max_element(x.begin(),x.end()); 
    };
};
```

There are several problems here:

1. `operator()` on a lambda is `const`, and you are trying to modify a member.
2. You are trying to assign the value to an external variable, but are capturing it by-value, so even if you made the lambda `mutable`, nothing would happen.
3. You are trying to assign a member of a class using a static function that does not take an instance of that class.
4. As dyp points out, [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) returns an iterator, not the actual element.

The lambda you want to write probably looks like this:

```
test t;
std::vector<int> v2(20);
fill_vector(v2, [&t](const std::vector<int>& x){
    t.max = *std::max_element(x.begin(), x.end());
});
```

Just change your `fill_vector()` function to take a callable, rather than something that has a callable.

Comment: The purpose of this exercise is to be able to use this lambda within `fill_vector`, not after it's completion. It's not clear this answer buys me that flexibility.

Comment: @Adam27X Updated specifically with the lambda you want to pass to `fill_vector`.